# GraphicsRow can't display the result that I want

Tags: graphics, output-formatting

Here is the code for my `GraphicsRow`:

```
GraphicsRow[
  {ParametricPlot[{Sin[3 t + Pi/2], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi}, 
     PlotStyle -> {Brown, Thin}],
   ListLinePlot[Table[{Sin[3 t + Pi/2], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], 
     PlotLabel -> "ListLinePlot Table", 
     AxesLabel -> {"Sin[3 t+Pi/2]", "Sin[t]"}]},
  AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]
```

Here is the output picture.

[image]

In my code, I set the options `AspectRatio -> 1, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}`. However, neither of these is achieved. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Try specifying `AspectRatio` and `PlotRange` for each plot.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi, but when I look the documentation in Mathematica. It's actually valid to put things behind all these  plots. `GraphicsRow[list,spacing]`. Here is an example.  ```GraphicsRow[Table[Graphics[Disk[], ImageSize -> 10 i], {i, 1, 5}], 
Alignment -> Top, Frame -> All]```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`GraphicsRow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/GraphicsRow.html)

> If the [elements of the 1st argument] are graphics, GraphicsRow will if possible make them all the same height, preserving their individual aspect ratios.

and that is what you got in your row of plots. What you probably would happier with is this:

```
GraphicsRow[
  {ParametricPlot[{Sin[3 t + Pi/2], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
     PlotLabel -> "ParametricPlot\n",
     PlotStyle -> Brown,
     AxesLabel -> {"Sin[3 t+Pi/2]", "Sin[t]"}], 
   ListLinePlot[Table[{Sin[3 t + Pi/2], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], 
     PlotLabel -> "ListLinePlot\n",
     AspectRatio -> 1,
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}},
     AxesLabel -> {"Sin[3 t+Pi/2]", "Sin[t]"}]},
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot_1]

or this:

```
GraphicsRow[
  {ParametricPlot[{Sin[3 t + Pi/2], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi},
     PlotLabel -> "ParametricPlot:\n{Sin[3 t+Pi/2], Sin[t]}\n",
     PlotStyle -> Brown],
   ListLinePlot[Table[{Sin[3 t + Pi/2], Sin[t]}, {t, 0, 2 Pi, 0.1}], 
     PlotLabel -> "ListLinePlot: \nTable of {Sin[3 t+Pi/2], Sin[t]}\n",
     AspectRatio -> 1,
     PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}]},
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: plot_2]

I prefer the rendering that appears immediately above. I think it conveys the plot annotations in a way that is clearer to the viewer.